# EXTJS4: how can i set the fieldlabel Width of a xtype:'textfield'

Tags: extjs, extjs4, textfield, xtype

I have a xytpe form, and i want so set the width of the fieldLabel and not the width of the label itself.

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    id: 'iln',
    name: 'iln',
    fieldLabel: 'Product-Number-Field-with-body-height',
    allowBlank: true,
    anchor: '100%'
}
```

I tried everything...its only changes the textfield, and not the width of the fieldlabel. Any help?
THANK YOU!

Comment: What do you mean "the width of the field label and not the label itself"?  And have you tried `labelWidth`? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-labelWidth

Comment: I want more space for the text infront ob the label. So when I dondt change the width, the Text "Product-Number-Field-with-body-height" has a break and goes into the new line. I tried `labelWidth` but it only changes the input field.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense.  "Space for the text in front of the label"?  There is no such thing.  Also, there is no way that changing the `labelWidth` changes the input field, it will change the width of the label.  Since you are using `anchor: 100%`, it may change both the label and field widths, but what you are saying cannot be true.

Comment: Yes you are right, the anchor was teh problem! THANK YOU!!

Comment: @kevhender - Please post an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: Done, thanks for following up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the `labelWidth` is changing the input field's width because you are using `anchor: 100%`.  Take this out and `labelWidth` should do more like you are expecting.